# Checkboxes with pylons

Tags: python, pylons

I have been trying to add some check boxes in a pylons mako. However I don't know how to get their values in the controller. It seems that it can only get the first value of the check boxes. I tried using form encode but i got several errors. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "I can only get the first value" means you've got a series of checkboxes with the same value for the 'name' attribute within your form?

Now, if that's the case and you're wanting a list of boolean values based on whether or not the boxes are checked or not, you'll need to do two things:

First, when you define your form elements using form encode on your checkbox, set it up such that a missing value on a checkbox element returns 'False.' This way, as the browser won't send a value over unless a checkbox is "on", you validation coerces the missing value to False.

```
    class Registration(formencode.Schema):  
        box = formencode.validators.StringBoolean(if_missing=False)
```

Next, assuming you want a list returned, you'll not be able to name all of your elements the same.  Pylons supports a nested structure, though.  Look at formencode.variabledecode.NestedVariables. In short, you'll need to define a NestedVariables instance as one of your class attributes and your form 'name' attributes will need to change in order to contain explicit indexes.

Edit.. here's a complete example I did real quick:

```
import logging
import pprint

import formencode
from pylons import request, response, session, tmpl_context as c, url
from pylons.controllers.util import abort, redirect
from pylons.decorators import validate

from testproj.lib.base import BaseController, render

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CheckList(formencode.Schema):
    box = formencode.validators.StringBoolean(if_missing=False)
    hidden = formencode.validators.String()

class EnclosingForm(formencode.Schema):
    pre_validators = [formencode.NestedVariables()]
    boxes = formencode.ForEach(CheckList())

class MyformController(BaseController):

    def index(self):
        schema = EnclosingForm()
        v = schema.to_python(dict(request.params))
        # Return a rendered template
        #return render('/myform.mako')
        # or, return a response
        response.content_type = 'text/plain'
        return pprint.pformat(v)
```

And then the query string?

```
boxes-0.box=true&boxes-0.hidden=hidden&boxes-1.box=true&
boxes-1.hidden=hidden&boxes-2.hidden=hidden
```

And lastly, the response:

```
{'boxes': [{'box': True, 'hidden': u'hidden'},
           {'box': True, 'hidden': u'hidden'},
           {'box': False, 'hidden': u'hidden'}]}
```

HTH

Comment: The hidden field ensures that NestedVariables sees there is supposed to be a form there.  Though, you might just be able to read the query string and munch it yourself if you're just dealing with a collection of checkboxes.